Add custom bash script to ubuntu auto-install ISO
I'm working on an Ubuntu auto-install ISO. I'm close to finishing it, and my last task is to add a custom bash script that will be run in late-commands stage.
I tried to search for someone who's already done it, but no luck.
Scenario:
I have two custom bash scripts which I would like to include in the ISO file, then copy them to the user's home directory during the installation (the user is created during installation in the 'user-data' section of user-data file). At the end of the installation, I would run those scripts.
This will be a single-user server without any connection to internet. I need to include 2 bash scripts (that I already have) into the ISO file (maybe in the nocloud/ directory?).
During auto-installation, these scripts have to be copied to the user's home directory (or any other directory in the filesystem like /var, /opt, etc.).
Once the installation is complete, I have to run those scripts (late-commands section of the user-data file). Now, I already have the scripts, I do know how to run a script at the end of the installation, but I don't know how/where to place them in the ISO file and I don't know how to copy scripts to a specific directory during the installation.
How can I solve this?
Thank you a lot

Please EDIT to clarify, don't answer in the comments. Comments are hard to read, easy to miss and can be deleted without warning. Also explain why you would need the scripts to be copied to the home directories of users since that seems very odd. You could add them to /etc/skel since files in that directory are copied to any new user's home when the user is created, but this really sounds like an XY problem, please edit and explain why this is needed.

No need to have them in /etc/skel/ it's a simple server with a single user. Those scripts will be run any time we need. but they have to be copied during the automated installation process. and run them immediately after the installation is completed.

I figured skel would be the natural place since anything there is copied to the home dir. So if you have them in /etc/skel/bin, then the ~/bin directory of your user will be automatically created when the user is created, and the files will be copied there.

FYI.  The users defined in user-data do not get created during installation.  They are created by cloud-init during the first boot after installation.
